# using iThemes Security wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

i have use iThemes Security plugin wordpress, and i change admin login page every day with that plugin, but in the security log section , i see hacker try login to my admin panel and that can Discovery my admin page.can you help me? no everyone has idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried brute force attack enabled.  You should not have to change the url to login each day

Comment: yes i have enable brute force attack protect.why im not change login url every day?

Comment: Why would you manually change the custom url each day?  If they are managing to find that url and attempting to login then I'd be asking if anything is snooping

Comment: Yes , probably. and i question how that can be find admin page every time i change that?